# MariaDB: How to install a second instance using MSI-Installer

Tags: mariadb, installation, instance, windows-10

I would like to install a second instance of MariaDB with MSI-Installer (Windows 10). The first instance is on drive C. When I want to install the second instance on drive D using MSI-Installer the installer recognizes that there is already an installation and asks if I want change/repair/remove. How can avoid this step and get the installation option?

Windows 10/ MariaDB 10.6.8

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with MSI, MariaDB MSI is not multiinstance-capable.

You can however install as many database instances as you want using mysql_install_db.exe, once you have installed MSI once.

Example call to create a new instance:

```
"C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.6\bin\mysql_install_db.exe" --datadir=D:\db2 --service=MariaDB2 --port=3307
```

creates you a new instance. You start it with "net start MariaDB2"

If you'd need to remove those instances, you'd have to do it yourself, with rmdir and "sc delete servicename"